# What rule did I use to split the alphabet

Tags: pattern

I have split the alphabet into two sets using a rule:

- **`A E F H I L M N O R S X`**
- **`B C D G J K P Q T U V W Y Z`**

What is the rule?

Comment: this actually just gave me an idea for a puzzle... not quite sure on yours though off the bat... gave it a few tries but I have to run.

Comment: @JulianRosen Doesn't look like a duplicate, as mine has a different division rule.

Comment: The linked puzzle has a list of 14 divisions, yours is number 10 on the list.

Comment: Hm, I didn't see that. Should I remove this question?

Comment: Don't remove this question. Leaving duplicates is better, makes it easier for people to find the first version. Plus there's an answer here already

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rule is

> The top set when spelled would start with a vowel and the bottom set would start with a consonant. For example x would be spelled ex(vowel) and z would be spelled zee(consonant)

Comment: +1 but please use spoilers in the answer.

Comment: yeah will do next time

Comment: Correct! (Wow, that was quick)